# Why can't the antiderivative of 1/x be found using the limit of the power rule?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

Which step does this go wrong?

$$\frac{d}{dx} x^n = nx^{n-1}$$

$$∫ \frac{d}{dx} \left(x^{n} \right) dx = ∫ n x^{n-1} dx$$

$$x^n + c = n ∫ x^{n-1} dx$$

$$\frac{x^n}{n} + c = ∫ x^{n-1} dx, n≠0$$

$$\lim_{n→0} \left[ \frac{x^{n}}{n} + c = ∫ x^{n-1} dx \right]$$

However

$$\lim_{n→0} \left[ \frac{x^{n}}{n}+c \right] DNE$$

Therefore

$$ \lim_{n→0} \left[ ∫ x^{ n-1} dx \right] DNE$$

I understand that $∫ x^{-1} dx = \ln(x)$, but why doesn't the limit work?

Comment: You are dividing by $0$...

Comment: @alvoi, yes that's what makes $x^n/n$ divergent, but if $x^n/n = ∫x^{n-1}dx$, their limits should be the same. Or I suppose you can do it without the division, and you get $\lim_{n→0} x^n = \lim_{n→0} n ∫ x^{n-1}dx ⇒ 1=0$

Comment: In a way, you can since $\ln(x)=\lim_{n\to0}\frac{x^n-1}{n}$

Comment: I think the real issue here is that... whenever you take the indefinite integral of some function (i.e. the integrand), the answer represents a **family** or set of functions whose derivative is the integrand. However, this does not imply that every function in that family has the same limit, as the OP assumes by taking the limit of both sides of the equation. We are only assured that every function in the family has the same derivative.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you cannot do limits of indefinite integrals

If you consider $0<a<b$ and the identity (for $n\neq0$):

$$\int_a^b x^{n-1}\ \mathrm dx = \frac{b^n-a^n}n$$

then if you do the limit for $n→0$ you get

$$\lim_{n\to0}\int_a^b x^{n-1}\ \mathrm dx = \lim_{n\to0}\frac{b^n-a^n}n$$

The limit in the RHS is $\log(b)-\log(a)$ so you really get that

$$\lim_{n→ 0} \int_a^b x^{n-1}\ \mathrm dx = \int_a^b x^{-1}\ \mathrm dx.$$

Note that, in general, you cannot swap arbitrarily the integral with the limit!

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea for this...

The step wrong was between steps $3$ and $4$, where, on the LHS I went from "$x^n+c = RHS$" to "$\frac{x^n}{n}+c=RHS"$

The limit definition of $\ln(x)$ is
$$\lim_{h→0} \left[\frac{x^h-1}{h}\right]$$

If I define $c=-1+n\cdot c_1$, we can rewrite steps 3 and on as

$$x^n-1+n\cdot c_1 = n∫x^{n-1}dx $$

$$\frac{x^n-1}{n} +c_1 = ∫x^{n-1}dx, n≠0 $$

$$\lim_{n→0}\left[\frac{x^n-1}{n} +c_1 = ∫x^{n-1}dx \right]$$

$$\lim_{n→0}\left[\frac{x^n-1}{n} +c_1\right] = \ln(x) + c_1$$

Therefore
$$\lim_{n→0}\left[ ∫ x^{n-1} dx \right] = \ln(x) + c_1$$

So essentially, the problem was I wrongly assumed $\frac{c}{n}$ was also a Real constant, and the value of that constant could have made the limit converge.

Please correct me if I've made a mistake.

Comment: I think the real issue here is that... whenever you take the indefinite integral of some function (i.e. the integrand), the answer represents a **family** or set of functions whose derivative is the integrand. However, this does not imply that every function in that family has the same limit, as the OP assumes by taking the limit of both sides of the equation. We are only assured that every function in the family has the same derivative.